# Select2 se bloquea en filas agregadas dinámicamente

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estimad@s, por favor estoy comenzando en la programación y me encuentro que al crear un detalle con filas dinámicas, en la primera columna hay un elemento select2 en la primera línea funciona bién pero en el resto de filas agregadas dinámicamente el elemento selec2 se bloquea.

```
<tbody>
                        <tr id="product0" >
                            <td style="width: 50%">

                            <select name='products[]' class="mi-selector" id='selector' required style="font-size:0.7em">
                                    <!-- <option value="">-- Seleccione el medicamento --</option> -->
                                    @foreach ($products as $product)
                                    <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->carc_med_codigo }} 
                                        - {{ $product->carc_med_descripcion }}
                                          {{ $product->carc_med_forma }}
                                          {{ $product->carc_med_concentracion }}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                            </select>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='0,00' class="form-control price" step="0.01" min="0.01" required/>                                  
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <input type="number" name="quantities[]" class="form-control quantities" value="1"  min="1" required/>
                            </td>
                            <td width="9%">
                                <input type="number" name="descuento[]" class="form-control descuento" placeholder="0 %" step="0" min="0" value="0" required/>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <input type="number" name="valor_descuento[]" class="form-control valor_descuento" readonly/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0,00' class="form-control total" readonly/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="product1"></tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Hola, falta código para entender tu problema correctamente, pero te agregaré algo que pudiera ser uno de tus problemas y que a mi me ha pasado en la generación dinámica de elementos con javascript. Al generar un elemento html dinámicamente, este no posee ciertas propiedades que se inicializan cuando carga la página, el ejemplo mas sencillo son las propiedades de escucha. Probablemente estés usando una propiedad que no existe por generar el elemento dinámicamente y eso rompa tu funcionamiento del programa.

Comment: Yo creo que solo te faltara hacerle un trigger('change') al select2 para que detecte los cambios

Answer (score 0):

Al agregar atributos u opciones nuevas a select debes decirle a select dos que se actualice para que las renderice correctamente. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$('#selector').selectpicker('refresh');
```